# How to declare a field as varchar(max) in Firebird

Tags: database, firebird, create-table

How can I declare this table with varchar(max) in Firebird?

```
CREATE TABLE MyUser
(
Id   INT,   -- unique id of user
Signature   VARCHAR(max),  
Login   VARCHAR(50),   
UserPassword   VARCHAR(100),    
CONSTRAINT PK_MyUser PRIMARY KEY (Id) 
);
COMMIT;
```

Is it possible?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Firebird doesn't have a type `VARCHAR(MAX)`. You either need to use [`VARCHAR(32765)`](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/html/en/refdocs/fblangref40/firebird-40-language-reference.html#fblangref40-datatypes-chartypes-varchar) assuming you are using a 1-byte character-set or `VARCHAR(8191)` (with UTF-8), or you need to use a [`BLOB SUB_TYPE TEXT`](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/html/en/refdocs/fblangref40/firebird-40-language-reference.html#fblangref40-datatypes-bnrytypes) (which is a blob type for text data).

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, it isn't.

Use `VARCHAR(32765)`, Firebird can hold up to 32,765 characters (max). Or you could also use `BLOB`.